# limit the speed of range component in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-components

I want to know if there is a way to control the speed of range component in ionic 3. That means a user couldn't be able to move the slider too fast or to slow, just at the specific speed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see all the input properties for Range component: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/range/Range/#input-properties

I am not sure what is your use case, but you can try to use

- debounce
- step

to limit the frequency of Range component value change.